# Do I need to use Espresso for my compose app?

Tags: android-espresso, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I cannot figure out which testing API to use for my instrumented tests on my app built using compose.

In the Android [testing docs](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/ui-tests#jetpack) it mentions 4 different APIs (espresso, compose, UI Automator, Roboelectric).

My intuition is that I would like to use Compose over Espresso, as it is built by Google and seems newer.

On the other hand Espresso is based on the view system and seems more redundant. For example, in this post by Manuel Vivo, it mentions that Espresso still uses AsyncTask. I am also having a lot of issues with Idling Resources in Espresso and believe that compose testing API does not face these issues.

So my question is: Is Espresso necessary when doing instrumentation tests on my compose app or can I just use the (newer) Compose test library?